# How to parse all <p> tags within a certain <div> tag?

Tags: python-3.x, dom, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse some html page.
I want to get all text information within the `<p>` tags under this `<div id="commentary">`
[link to image of that html script content which I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKPxZ.png)

When I use `find_all` to get all of the `<p>` tags, the list contains only the first one. I used to following code to count the no. of `<p>` tags present under `<div>`. You can clearly see from the above image that there are around 19 `<p>` tags within that highlighted `<div>` tag, still my code prints out 1.

```
content = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'company-profile'})
points = content.find('div', attrs={'id':'commentary'})
count = 0
for point in points.find_all('p'):
    count = count + 1
print(count)
print(points.text)
```

I don't know why is this happening and why the `find_all` method wont return the complete list.
I also tried using the `points.text` to print all of the text within `<div id="commentary">` tag, but it prints contents of first `<p>` tag only.

```
(mlenv) chirag@debian10:~/ML/Finaments$ python main.py
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

State Bank of India is a Fortune 500 company. It is an Indian Multinational, Public Sector banking and financial services statutory body headquartered in Mumbai. It is the largest and oldest bank in India with over 200 years of history.#

1
1

Ratios (Q3FY21)
Capital Adequacy Ratio - 14.50%
Net Interest Margin - 3.34%
Gross NPA - 4.77%
Net NPA - 1.23%
CASA Ratio - 45.15%#




(mlenv) chirag@debian10:~/ML/Finaments$ ^C
(mlenv) chirag@debian10:~/ML/Finaments$
```

Those 1's are the from `print(count)` and then it only prints the content of first `<p>` tag from `print(points.text)`.
I have just started using beautifulsoup, please help me.

Comment: Can you give that url so it will be better for understanding and also if your are looping through `p` tags so you can `print(point.text)` and it will show i guess!

Comment: Here is the link - https://www.screener.in/company/sbin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go after the direct url that has that info. You'll need to pass in there the correct cookies and csrf tokens though:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.screener.in/wiki/company/3188/commentary/'
headers= {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
'referer': 'https://www.screener.in/company/SBIN/consolidated/',
'x-csrftoken': 'E8zDjm7CtmSqCM2B9rTYPXTcPMJ22w2oynWzWzT4bCgAIaKkt4DmrirBSEPdCP0W',
'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.69436223.1621345270; _ga=GA1.2.2056656539.1621345271; _gid=GA1.2.1452432592.1621345271; csrftoken=E8zDjm7CtmSqCM2B9rTYPXTcPMJ22w2oynWzWzT4bCgAIaKkt4DmrirBSEPdCP0W; sessionid=mrdcmrlqpe72dqjrqgtrb2m2v375sjv0; _gat_UA-2456523-7=1'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

count = 0
for point in soup.find_all('p'):
    count = count + 1
print(count)
print(soup.text)
```

**Output:**

```
19

Ratios (Q3FY21)
Capital Adequacy Ratio - 14.50%
Net Interest Margin - 3.34%
Gross NPA - 4.77%
Net NPA - 1.23%
CASA Ratio - 45.15%#
Branch Network
Presently, the bank operates a network of 22,330 branches and ~58,000 ATMs across India. It also operates ~71,000 business correspondent outlets across India.#
Market Share
The bank has a market share of 22.84% in deposits and 19.69% share in advances in India. It has a strong customer base of ~45 crore customers.#
Loan Book
Retail loans account for 39% of the loan book, followed by corporate (37%), SME (14%) and Agriculture (10%).#
Retail Book - Home loans account for 68% of the retail book, followed by xpress credit (22%), auto loans (9%), personal gold loans (2%) and others (9%).#
Exposure
The bank has a well-diversified loan book exposed to various sectors. Top sectors include home loans (23%), infrastructure (15%), services (12%) and agriculture (10%).
~75% of the corporate advances are rated A and better ratings from rating agencies. 38% of the corporate book accounts for PSUs & Govt. departments.#
Segmental NPAs
Presently, the total NPAs of the bank stands at 1,17,244 crores. agriculture segment accounts for the major ratio of NPAs i.e. 13.71% of all loans are NPA. Corporate segment accounts for 59,400 crores worth of NPAs i.e. 51% of total NPAs of the bank.#
International Business
The bank has a global footprint with a network of 233 branches/offices in 32 countries.# It has  presence in USA, Canada, Brazil, Russia, Germany, France, Turkey, Australia, Bangladesh, Nepal, Sri Lanka and other countries.#
Presently, Overseas business accounts for 3% of total deposits# and 13% of total advances.#
Government Business
SBI has always been the banker of choice to the government of India and is the market leader in government business. It had turnover of ~52,50,000 lakh crores and commissions of ~3,700 crores from government business in FY20.#
Financial Inclusion Business
The bank has ~71,000 BC outlets which has primary focus on financial inclusion customers.# The bank accounts for 40% of all PMJDY accounts i.e. more than 12 crore accounts.# Presently, the deposits from PMJDY accounts are ~42,500 crores i.e. 1.2% of total deposits of the bank.
Digital Metrics
Increasing digitization resulted in ~40% of asset accounts and ~60% of liability customers added via digital channels in FY21.# 67% of all transactions were initiated through digital channels in 2020 which is up from 58% in the previous year.#
Subsidiaries Operations
The bank owns various subsidiaries which are engaged in related business activities :-
1. SBI Capital Markets Ltd (100% stake) -  SBICAP is a leading investment banker, offering investment banking and corporate advisory services to clients across three product categories i.e. project advisory and structured finance, equity capital markets and debt capital markets.
This company further has wholly owned subsidiaries in related businesses viz. SBICAP Securities, SBICAP Trustee Co., SBICAP Ventures & others.#
2. SBI DHFI Ltd (72% stake) - It is a primary dealer and supports the book building process and provide depth and liquidity to secondary markets in G-Sec. It also deals in money market instruments, non G-Sec debt instruments, amongst others.#
3. SBI Cards and Payment Services Ltd (69% stake) - It is a non-banking financial company that offers extensive credit card portfolio to individual cardholders and corporate clients. It has diversified customer acquisition network that enables to engage prospective customers across multiple channels.#
The IPO of SBI Cards was launched in March 2020 wherein the company sold ~13 crore equity shares for a consideration of ₹10,350 crores.#
4. SBI Life Insurance Co. Ltd (57.6% stake) - It is one of the leading life insurance company in India which offers a wide range of individual and group insurance solutions that meet various life stage needs of customers.#
5. SBI Funds Management Pvt Ltd (63% stake) - It is a JV between SBI and AMUNDI (France). It is an asset management company with the fastest CAGR of 33% as against industrial average of 14% in the last 3 years.#
6. SBI General Insurance Company Ltd (70% stake) - It is a general insurance company which focuses on profitable growth in banc-assurance channel along  with other distribution channels and line of businesses. It is first non-life insurance company in India to cross 6,000 crores in a decade of operations.#
Amalgamation of Associate Banks
In March 2017, the bank acquired its 5 associate state banks and Bharatiya Mahila Bank by allotting ~13.5 crore equity shares of SBI.#
```

Comment: Thanks @chitown88, but why did you use post request? I thought we need to use GET method and then use `response.text` to get the html doc, that's what I passed to `BeautifulSoup()`. Also where do I find those cookies and csrf tokens?

Comment: You find that in the dev tools (Ctrl-Sft-i) when you load the page (you may need to refresh the page) and see the requests made. It tells you the method and the query parameters, requests headers and all that stuff in there.